# How would I input Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); for JOptionpane?

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

How do I initiate a system.in command for JOptionPane.
I tried:

```
JOptionPane input= new JOptionPane(System.in);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @coder888 Are you just asking how to get input from a `JOptionPane`?  You don't need `System.in` for that.  If that's not your question, please rephrase.

Comment: You don't, that's not how user/keyboard input works in GUIs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would better answered through one of the many available tutorials, like [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Well, I'm voting to close as unclear, since I still can't say for sure what he's asking.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are confusing the console with dialog boxes. Scanner is used when getting input from the keyboard.

JOptionPane is used for a dialog box. if you want to get back input then you can write

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter anything");
```

Comment: You can user Scanner for things other than keyboard input, although that may be the most common use, especially for beginners.

Comment: @DM  I agree on that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("InputDialog Example");
String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    frame, 
    "Enter the text below"
);
```

Comment: I think JFrame is not needed in this case, JOptionPane has it's own inputbox.

Comment: That is correct.